# xinetd server return value is not readable

Tags: c, linux, sockets, xinetd

I have enabled all xinetd services and I am calling it from the c program. Everything works fine but when I call the time service, it returns 4 bytes value that is unreadable. Following is one sample output.

[image: c program output]

So, How do I convert this output into a readable format?

Comment: Better forward to Unix & Linux site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_Protocol):

> The server then sends the time as a 32-bit unsigned integer in binary format and in network byte order, representing the number of seconds since 00:00 (midnight) 1 January, 1900 GMT, and closes the connection.

After decoding to native byte order (Via `ntohl()` or friends), you can then do what you like with the value. Note that it won't work as-is with functions that take a `time_t` like `ctime()` because the normal Unix epoch (The 0 point) is a different date. Luckily, that can be worked around by subtracting the offset of the epoch from the time protocol's 0 point from the provided time.

---

Here's an example program that connects to the time service of the given IP address or hostname passed as its sole command line argument and prints out both the value received and a human-readable date string (Using the above mentioned offset to convert to a normal Unix time value):

```c
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <unistd.h>

// 00:00  1 Jan 1970 GMT in RFC 868 time format.
#define EPOCH_OFFSET 2208988800U

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  if (argc != 2) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s hostname\n", argv[0]);
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }

  struct addrinfo *res;
  struct addrinfo hints = {
    .ai_family = AF_UNSPEC,
    .ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM
  };
  int err;

  if ((err = getaddrinfo(argv[1], "time", &hints, &res)) != 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "getaddrinfo: %s\n", gai_strerror(err));
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }

  for (struct addrinfo *addr = res; addr; addr = addr->ai_next) {
    int s = socket(addr->ai_family, addr->ai_socktype, addr->ai_protocol);
    if (s >= 0) {
      if (connect(s, addr->ai_addr, addr->ai_addrlen) == 0) {
        uint32_t raw;
        if (read(s, &raw, sizeof raw) != sizeof raw) {
          fprintf(stderr, "Could not read complete time.\n");
          close(s);
          freeaddrinfo(res);
          return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
        raw = ntohl(raw);
        printf("Got raw time: %" PRIu32 "\n", raw);

        time_t tval = raw - EPOCH_OFFSET;
        printf("Converted time: %s", ctime(&tval));

        close(s);
        freeaddrinfo(res);
        return 0;
      } else {
        close(s);
      }
    }
  }
  
  printf("Unable to connect to %s's time server.\n", argv[1]);
  freeaddrinfo(res);
  return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

Comment: Interestingly, the original [RFC 868](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc868) doesn't say anything about byte order or signed-ness - it even has an example of a negative time (But see the [errata](https://www.rfc-editor.org/errata_search.php?rfc=868) about that).